# How to change the order of WHERE and ORDER BY in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple query that filters a 100M row table for `fk_id` and returns rows sorted by `col1, col2`.

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE fk_id=$fk_id
ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Both `col1` and `col2` are indexed `DESC TIMESTAMP` columns. `fk_id` is also indexed.

`ANALYZE` shows that Postgres first orders the table by `col1` and `col2` and then filters out rows by `fk_id`.

---

A lookup query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE fk_id=$fk_id` is 1000x faster than the query above, and so I want to apply the `WHERE` filter first.

Comment: `create index ix1 on table (fk_id, col1, col2);`. This index should seriously improve performance, unless your table is very skewed.

Comment: Has your table been vacuumed and analyzed recently?  If you have performance issues, you should always do that first, then look at the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: `ANALYZE shows that Postgres first orders the table by col1 and col2 and then filters out rows by fk_id`. No it does not. the sort will appear at the top because it is the last operation. You need to read from bottom to top.